# иерархия пакета

Tags: java

Хочу для себя реализовать пакет "постройки". Что должно быть в пакете. Я читал и представляю себе так что должен быть абстрактный класс "дом", наследующие классы "замок" "высотка" "коттедж" и интерфейс "информация" который будет описывать функционал этих построек. Подскажите в правильном направлении иду или нет. Не могу найти нормальные примеры а те которые немного подходят просто копирую но понимания нет. Если возможно скажите кратко какие поля и методы должны быть реализованы в каждом классе и в интерфейсе.

Comment: Зависит от того, какую задачу решаете. Если вы не знаете, какие методы вам нужны — значит вам, видимо, этот пакет в принципе не нужен, и делать его просто нет смысла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начните так

```
abstract Building { ... }

class Castle extends Building { ... } 

class Appartment extends Building { ... } 

class Tower extends Building { ... }
```

Идея абстракции - вы уходите от специфики и выделяете только общие моменты присущие всем.

Строение -> Гараж, Дом, ....

А если идти по принципам [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) чтобы быть правильным то

[L](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) - Принцип подстановки Барбары Лисков

> Этот принцип является важнейшим критерием для оценки качества
> принимаемых решений при построении иерархий наследования.
> Сформулировать его можно в виде простого правила: тип S будет подтипом
> Т тогда и только тогда, когда каждому объекту oS типа S соответствует
> некий объект oT типа T таким образом, что для всех программ P,
> реализованных в терминах T, поведение P не будет меняться, если oT
> заменить на oS.
>
> Более простыми словами можно сказать, что поведение наследующих
> классов не должно противоречить поведению, заданному базовым классом,
> то есть поведение наследующих классов должно быть ожидаемым для кода,
> использующего переменную базового типа.

Читая данное утверждение особо-то и создавать и наследовать много классов то и не хочется.

Ещё пару слов про интерфейсы.
В них обычно выносят методы классов которые не возможно наследовать по принципу Лисков.

Comment: так я и сделал как вы написали, только как к этому всему еще интерфейс добавить и что в нем будет если все методы можно описывать в абстрактном классе и переопределять и добавлять в подклассах? Или в классах должны быть только какие то определенные методы не описывающие функционал зданий?

Comment: В интерфейс скидывают поведение классов которых не возможно объединить по проинципу Лисков. В случае невозможности наследования используйте интерфейсы